# How to Make Zip Archive of Same Date Files in Python

Tags: python, zip

hi    I have prepared software that meets the following conditions, but if there     are too many files in the folder (for example 100,000), the program starts to throw all files into a
single zip file after a certain period of time.

I'm using python 3.7

1. There'il be dates over 2 days old.
2. files will be the same date.
3. only files with .log extension.
4. the date of the file to the name of the zip file.

```
import os
import datetime
import time
from zipfile import ZIP_DEFLATED, ZipFile
import zipfile
m = os.listdir()

bugun=datetime.datetime.today()
fark=datetime.timedelta(days=2)
dun=(bugun-fark).date()
print ( dun,"tarihinden eski dosyalar zipleniyor")
zaman=time.mktime(dun.timetuple()) #There'il be dates over 2 days old.

for i in m:
    if os.stat(i).st_mtime<zaman and i.endswith(".log"): #
        x = os.stat(i).st_mtime
        y = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).date()
        print(i,"Dosyası Sıkıştırılıyor")

        if not os.path.exists(str(y)+".zip"):
            try:
                import zlib
                mode = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
            except:
                mode = zipfile.ZIP_STORED
            zip_dosyasi = (str(y)+".zip")
            zip = ZipFile(zip_dosyasi, 'w', mode)
            print (zip_dosyasi,"dosyası oluşturuldu")

        zip.write(i)
        print(i,"Dosyası" ,zip_dosyasi,"Zip Klasörüne Taşındı")
        os.remove(i)
time.sleep(0.1)


print("İşlem Tamamlandı")
```

Comment: You ask the question precisely enough to be answered. But you should use minimally executable code, and that is what you'd do anyway to debug the issue yourself. I would guess that the problem originates in a stockpile of zip actions threatening to overflow some buffer, with corrective action taken internal to the zipfile library. Can you reproduce the problem with a large directory of files that all meet your conditions? If so, remove the conditions from your code and your question to be more minimal, isolating the problem for your own use as well as that of the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

when you assign a new `ZipFile` to the global variable `zip`, you lose the binding to the  object previously bound to `zip`. Place that assignment inside a function to make each assignment of `zip` using a different local variable.

The [documentation for this library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html) doesn't provide a clue as to the source of your problem or the solution I think.

Also, why `import zlib` if you never call it? Separately, no reason to put the import statement inside the for loop. After a file is imported in Python, additional import statements for the same library are ignored.